# How do I refer to savefiledialog dynamically

Tags: .net, vb.net, methods, reference, savefiledialog

I have to use a savefiledialog and I want to refer to it from code that is without showing it perform the save click( like we use .performclick methods or simply refering to the sub but that doesn't seem to work with savefiledialog class).
How can I accomplsh this?

Any pointers or ways

P.S. I am trying to save it as html file

Comment: SAveFileDialog is used to get from the user the required inputs. If you want to save a file without user input then there is no need to use SaveFileDialog but you use just the System.IO classes.

Comment: It sounds like you've got code that runs after the save dialog is shown, but you want to run it without showing the dialog.  If that is the case, simply move that code out to its own method and call it directly.  You can save the selected filename in a class level variable so it is available to all your methods that need it.

Comment: @idle_Mind, I can't understand your statement clearly, please elaborate, "simply move that code out to its own method and call it directly"

Answer (score 0):

> I can't understand your statement clearly, please elaborate, "simply
>   move that code out to its own method and call it directly"

I'm guessing you have something like this:

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    If SaveFileDialog1.ShowDialog = Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK Then
        Dim FileName As String = SaveFileDialog1.FileName
        ' ... do something with "FileName" ...
    End If
End Sub
```

You'd want to move the "do something" part out to its own method like this:

```
Private FileName As String = ""

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    If SaveFileDialog1.ShowDialog = Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK Then
        Me.FileName = SaveFileDialog1.FileName
        SaveToFile()
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub SaveToFile()
    If Me.FileName <> "" Then
        ' ... do something with "FileName" ...
    End If
End Sub
```

It's a subtle difference, but now you can call `SaveToFile()` again from somewhere else without first displaying the dialog.  *Assuming you've either put a valid value into FileName, or the user has selected one for you.

Comment: Well now I understand the code, and it worked after some minor changes

Comment: Yes...if the user clicks the button.  If you don't want a savefiledialog to **EVER** appear, then why use one at all?!  This is what Steve was saying.  You don't need a SaveFileDialog to perform file I/O.  Your very first statement of `I have to use a savefiledialog and I want to refer to it from code that is without showing it` seems like the wrong way to go about things.  Explain in more detail what you're trying to do if this doesn't help your situation.

Comment: Well I have to save the text inside a richtextbox as an html file with the name and directory for it in textbox1, on the click event of button1. It should then save the file as html.

Comment: So the FileName is in TextBox1.  If the TextBox is empty, then you want the SaveFileDialog to appear first?...and otherwise just save the file without the dialog?

Answer (score 0):

I did it the way you mentioned i.e, saving directly without savefiledialog, and it works

```
  My.Computer.FileSystem.WriteAllText(SaveFileDialog1.FileName, Form1.rt1.Text, False)
```